# multiple message from one producer to rabbitmq multiple consumers on a queue - and reply back the message who ever finishes first to producer

Tags: python-3.x, rabbitmq, pika, python-pika

I'm very new to **RabbitMQ** and **Pika** libraries in **Python**.

Could anyone help to solve this scenario where I have one producer with multiple tasks to be submitted to one rabbitmq queue with multiple consumers?

The consumers need to reply back to the producer which ever the consumer finishes first.